# Ruby on rails: Has_many self referencial - List objects in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bidirectional

i'm doing this tutorial http://cobwwweb.com/bi-directional-has-and-belongs-to-many-on-a-single-model-in-rails for doing a parent-child association with multiple parents for each child.

I can already associate parents with childs. But now I don't understand how can I list the parents and their children

This is my PerformanceIndicator model:

```
class PerformanceIndicator < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :improvement_actions
  has_ancestry


  has_many :left_parent_associations, :foreign_key => :left_parent_id, :class_name => 'PerformanceIndicatorAssociation'
  has_many :left_associations, :through => :left_parent_associations, :source => :right_parent

  has_many :right_parent_associations, :foreign_key => :right_parent_id, :class_name => 'PerformanceIndicatorAssociation'
  has_many :right_associations, :through => :right_parent_associations, :source => :left_parent

  def associations
    (left_associations + right_associations).flatten.uniq
  end   
end
```

And this is my PerformanceIndicatorAssociation model:

```
class PerformanceIndicatorAssociation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :left_parent, :class_name => 'PerformanceIndicator'
  belongs_to :right_parent, :class_name => 'PerformanceIndicator'
end
```

How can I list the parents and their child like this?

```
Parent1
  Child1
  Child2
Parent2
  Child1
  Child2
```

Comment: _Sidenote:_ this is by no means `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship, these are two independent `has_many` relationships.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `left_associations` are the parents of a PerformanceIndicator and `right_associations` are the children, your scope needs to look like this:

```
scope :without_parents, -> {
  joins("LEFT JOIN performance_indicator_associations ON performance_indicator_associations.left_parent_id = performance_indicators.id")
    .where(performance_indicator_associations: {right_parent_id: nil})
}
```

Now, you should get the following:

```
pi1 = PerformanceIndicator.create(name: 'parent1')
pi2 = PerformanceIndicator.create(name: 'parent2')

ci1 = PerformanceIndicator.create(name: 'child1')
ci2 = PerformanceIndicator.create(name: 'child2')

pi1.right_associations << ci1
pi1.right_associations << ci2
pi2.right_associations << ci2

PerformanceInficator.withour_parents.each do |parent| # => [p1, p2]
  # do stuff with parent
  parent.right_associations.each do |child|
    # do stuff with child
    # assume child is ci2
    child.left_associations   # => [p1, p2]
   end
 end
```